# Should I seperate input validation and DB query?

Tags: node.js, validation, software-design

I am now working on a API back-end. I've written a series of functions to query a database, like:

(yes, NodeJS)

```
function addGuys(guys, cb) {
  var sql = 'INSERT INTO guys ...';
  guys.ForEach(function(guy) {
    // Construct sql according to keys given in `guy`
    // Validate here?
    // add col names, values to sql statment, etc
  }
  // Execute query
}
```

The problem now is, should I validate input in these DB functions, or should I validate input before sending it to the DB functions? The latter seems cleaner, but I am a novice and still not sure. Any advice will be welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not construct SQL directly yourself at all.  Instead you should use a library for that, which does its own validation and escaping.  A popular example would be http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/

Comment: Thanks! The question remains though. Suppose I really want to have a better grip on how to construct my queries, or perhaps go through the basics before using any frameworks. How should I structure db query and validation?

Comment: @ChungLunYuen: No.  Don't do that.  If you don't want to use a "framework" that's fine, but under no circumstance should you be constructing SQL manually.  It's a security vulnerability in the making.  You use some kind of library for this.  If you're asking how to write a DB library that'd be very different.